# getting doctrine package error after run an exist laravel project in my system

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine, laravel-doctrine

I have just setup a laravel exist project but i am getting an error while i run php artisan command or any migrate command whenever i run any command i got doctrine package error. i am not getting idea how to fix it and run this project.i have also added snapshot of error [doctrine lib error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8HML.png)

step what i did till now with php version 7 and mysql version 14.14

1. clone exist project in my /var/www/html folder
2. run command composer update --no-scripts
3. checked vendor folder everything is created in vendor
4. now if try to run any command it throws doctrine package error which is in my image i attached above

Comment: You should have a look to your logs (storage/logs.php to get the whole backtrace)

Comment: but there is same error which is in  snapshot i have attached above a blank Array